# Nero Mist granite countertop

Tags: granite

I'm in the process of choosing a material for a new kitchen counter.  One that I'm considering is a honed Nero Mist granite.  I'm trying to find out from someone who has the same type of granite how often they have to seal it.  I've read that some granite needs yearly sealing.  Concerning black granite, I've read that they don't need sealing as often.  However, that seems to be canceled out by another source which stated that honed granite often needs to be sealed more frequently that highly polished granite.  If you have this material, can you please let me know how it's holding up and how often you have to seal it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I sealed some nearly black granite over 20 years ago and it never needed resealing. The first time food oil touched it , it made a mark in the granite. So I went to the dealer and he sold me a 500 ml bottle of a clear oil-like liquid. It worked great; it needed less than one ounce/sq.yd. ... Found it in my garage- PSI, premium silicon impregnator ( Lithofin brand), made in Germany.

Comment: Was your granite polished or honed?  Polished has a mirror-like finish, honed has a flatter finish because the surface is more irregular.  The question is really asking whether honed granite needs sealing more often.

Comment: Polished. It has often been exposed to oily foods with no problem.